# How to configure Vue to automatically import some SASS styles into .scss files with the new @use rule?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass

**tl;dr:** How to automatically import some `.scss` files with global styles into both **other `.scss` files** as well as into Vue's **Single File Components**?

---

I have a Vue project configured to automatically import some global styles:

```js
// vue.config.js

module.exports = {

  // Automatically import global styles:
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        prependData: `
          @use "@/global/styles/_Colors.scss";
          @use "@/global/styles/_Mixins.scss";
        `
      }
    }
  }

}
```

This works perfectly for automatically importing my global styles with @use into every Single File Component:

```vue
<!-- Component.vue -->

<template>...</template>

<style lang="scss">
.hero {
  background: Colors.$primary; // _Colors.scss was automatically imported with @use!
}
</style>
```

But, it doesn't work if I define my component styles in a separate file, and then import that file into the component, like this:

```scss
// ComponentStyles.scss

.hero {
  background: Colors.$primary; // Error! "There's no module with the namespace "Colors"
}
```

```vue
<!-- Component.vue -->

<template>...</template>

<style lang="scss">
@use "./ComponentStyles";
</style>
```

I've tried using the `style-resources-loader` plugin following the sample configuration in the Vue docs for [Automatic Imports](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#automatic-imports), like this:

```js
// vue.config.js

const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    const types = ['vue-modules', 'vue', 'normal-modules', 'normal']
    types.forEach(type => addStyleResource(config.module.rule('scss').oneOf(type)))
  },
}

function addStyleResource (rule) {
  rule.use('style-resource')
    .loader('style-resources-loader')
    .options({
      patterns: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, './src/global/styles/_Colors.scss'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, './src/global/styles/_Mixins.scss')
      ],
    })
}
```

And it worked. Kind of. I now had access to my global styles even inside `.scss` files (not just in SFCs). But, a new error emerged. Importing my local component styles with `@use` inside a Vue component no longer works.

```vue
<!-- Component.vue -->

<template>...</template>

<style lang="scss">
@use "./ComponentStyles";
// Error! @use rules must be written before any other rules.
</style>
```

I guess that, in the second approach, the `style-resources-loader` plugin is using `@import` rules or dumping the content of my global styles above my local `@use` rules in SFCs. That would result in the error I saw, but I couldn't find any option to control that.

---

#### Goal:

I want to be able to automatically prepend the `.scss` files I import into my SFCs with `@use` rules that expose my global styles to those files (much like the `loaderOptions` property in `vue.config.js` from my first approach allowed me to do in SFCs). I want to keep my SFCs as clean as possible, and that's why I prefer to have my component styles broken down into separate files.

So, **is there any way to automatically import some `.scss` files into both Vue's Single File Components and into other `.scss` files with `@use` rules?**

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: were you able to find a solution to that? would be helpful to share

Comment: @DS_web_developer Hi! I was able to find a partial solution. Just shared it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update: Mostly Solved

I managed to:

1. Automatically import global Sass styles into all Vue components.
2. Easily access global Sass styles from `.scss` or `.sass` files.

The only slight annoyance is that I have to manually import my global styles into Sass files (they're only automatically imported into Vue components). But, the setup I'm using supports aliases, so I don't need to worry about constructing relative paths or updating my import statements if I move my styling files. Also, unlike my previous setup, the new one has full support for the latest `@use` syntax.

### Setup Guide

Note: I'm now using Vite instead of the Vue Cli.

Note 2: **I made a [minimal repo][1] in case you prefer to explore a more detailed demonstration of how to set this up.**

#### vite.config.js

```ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import path from 'path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],

  // Config Docs: https://vitejs.dev/config/#css-preprocessoroptions
  css: {
    // make global variables and mixins available in all Vue components:
    preprocessorOptions: {
      sass: {
        additionalData: `
        @use './src/global/Index' as GlobalStyles
        `
        // ...I chose to merge all my GlobalStyles into one single scope here,
        // but you can also import them individually.
      }
      //...you can change the key above from 'sass' to 'scss' if you use scss in
      // your Vue components. You could also repeat the same settings for both if
      // you alternate between sass and scss in your components. Note that this
      // distinction is not needed for the ".sass" or ".scss"" files you import into your
      // Vue components. Those are handled by the alias resolver below, which will work
      // regardless of the Sass file extension you use.
    }
  },

  resolve: {
    alias: [
      {
        // This will help us use our global styles from regular sass files:
        find: '@styles',
        replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/global/Index')
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

#### Global Variables Example

```sass
// Colors.sass
$aquamarine: hsl(160, 100%, 75%)
$deepSlateGray: hsl(160, 25%, 5%)
$faintAqua: hsla(160, 100%, 95%, 0.25)
```

#### Global Mixins Example

```sass
// Mixins.sass
@mixin useCenteredFlex($direction)
  display: flex
  flex-direction: $direction
  justify-content: center
  align-items: center
```

#### Global Styles Aggregator

Note: This is in the same directory as `Colors.sass` and `Mixins.sass`, and is the file I'm automatically importing into all Vue components and matching the `@style` alias to.

```sass
// Index.sass
@forward 'Colors'
@forward 'Mixins'
```

#### Demo of Accessing Global Styles from a Vue Component

```vue
<template>...</template>
<style lang="sass">
body
  @include GlobalStyles.useCenteredFlex(column)  // <- using a globally available mixin
  background-color: GlobalStyles.$deepSlateGray // <- using a globally available variable
</style>
```

#### Demo of Accessing Global Styles from a Sass file

```sass
// Here we need to reference the alias we set up in vite.config.js to access our GlobalStyles
@use '@styles' as GlobalStyles
  
h1
  color: GlobalStyles.$aquamarine // <- using a global variable
```

```
  [1]: https://github.com/mareszhar/demo-asiivwv-so
```